# How to remove first data from data class?

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have two data classes `DataClass1` and `DataClass2` where `DataClass2` is identical to `DataClass1` except that it lacks the first variable.

```
data class DataClass1(
    val entry0: Any,
    val entry1: Any,
...
    val entryN: Any
)

data class DataClass2(

    val entry1: Any,
...
    val entryN: Any
)
```

Suppose I have `dc1` as an instance of dataClass1 and want to obtain the corresponding dataClass2. version (i.e., "remove" `entry0`). I know that for a simple case, I could just do

```
dc2 = DataClass2(
val entry1 = dc1.entry1,
val entry2 = dc1.entry2
)
```

But is there a way to this for the case where the number of entries is variable?

Comment: Why would the number of entries ever be "unknown"?

Comment: Also, can you change `DataClass1` and `DataClass2`? Or are they out of your control?

Comment: @Sweeper I changed "unknown" to "variable" in case that makes more sense. DataClass1 is out of control. DataClass2 is not.

Comment: So you want a general solution on how to map fields from one class to another class..?

Comment: @0x150 I'm not sure how to phrase it with the appropriate technical terms. I think the example should pretty clearly explain what I want to do though.

Comment: @nayriz assuming you mean that you want to map fields from one class to another, we used to do this at work for copying data structures. it is a *horrible*, and i mean, ABHORRENTLY BAD idea to do this. It's a mistake waiting to happen, it's a bug waiting to be let free.
You should rather make a method on the data structure itself to convert it to another type, to stay safe in the realm of compiler errors and type safety. Doing it dynamically is a very bad idea.

Comment: @0x150 OK, then how do you do it by "make a method on the data structure itself to convert it to another type" if the best you can do is extend the class with a method?

Comment: @nayriz i'm going to write this as an answer to the post, give me a second

Comment: There is no automatic or straightforward way to do this. If you don't have that many of such classes (e.g. 10) then I suggest to not overengineer, but write the code for conversions manually. In Kotlin, the most idiomatic way would be to create extension functions like: `DataClass1.toDataClass2()`. If you have a lot of such classes, they have many fields and/or you expect you need to add more fields with time, so manually written functions would introduce a maintenance of keeping them in sync, then you can look for [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/) - it does exactly this.

Comment: @broot I wouldn't mind a non-straightforward way if actually know one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map fields from one class to another to help with data transfer, doing it dynamically is a bad idea. Compiler errors and type safety dont exist in the realm of reflection.

Instead, a better alternative would be to make a method on the class, to allow it to decide how it should convert to another type.
(This is java code as an example, I am not very well versed with kotlin)

```java
public <T> T convertTo(Class<T> clazz) {
    if (String.class.equals(clazz)) return this.toString(); // example conversion
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot convert to "+clazz);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @0x150 and @broot warnings about the fragility of this kind of system design.

I am assuming dc1 is not yours, dc2, is within your control.

In the comments, did you spot @broot's reference to extension functions.  The magic of these is that you can apply them to classes (like dc1) which are out of your control.

I also like broot's suggestion of mapstruct, but if want another solution.  It's kind-of reflection but via serialization.

1. Pick a Object <> Json serialization library, e.g. Jackson
2. Serialize the class you don't have control of (`dc1`) into JSON (or a Node map)
3. Now determine which is the target class. You are not clear if that is well known, e.g. `dc2` or if that is part of the problem.  If you need to do matching, then perhaps you can do this using the Set of keys in that JSON
4. Then create an instance of `dc2` by deserializing the JSON, having previously annotated `dc2` with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` or the equivalent for your serialization library

this works

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class  T {
    data class DataClass1(
        val entry0: Any,
        val entry1: Any,
        val entryN: Any
    )

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    data class DataClass2(
        val entry1: Any,
        val entryN: Any
    )

    val mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
        .addModule(KotlinModule.Builder().configure(KotlinFeature.StrictNullChecks, true).build())
        .build()
    fun convert(dc1: DataClass1): DataClass2 = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(dc1), DataClass2::class.java)

    @Test
    fun convertTest() {
        val dc1: DataClass1 = DataClass1(44, 55, 66)
        val dc2: DataClass2 = convert(dc1)
        dc2 shouldBe DataClass2(55, 66)
    }
}
```